# How to resolve this object Leak?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

according to picture it report an object leak 
how can i fix this issue?

[image]

Comment: This is realy of no help. Please try to explain your situation better

Comment: Can you cut and paste the actual code into your question? The print screen is not readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `[item copy]`, your `stories` collection will retain the `item` copy which will over-retain the copy. Add it to `stories` directly, or if you must make a copy for immutability reasons, try `[[item copy] autorelease]`.

Answer (score 3):

You are copying an object and adding it to an array without decrementing its refcount, which is a leak. You should change

```
[stories addObject:[item copy]];
```

to either

```
[stories addObject:item];
```

or

```
[stories addObject:[[item copy] autorelease];
```

Depending on whether you want a copy of the item, or the item itself.

Also, next time cut and past your code so that it is readable.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Louis Gerbarg

Answer (score 0):

Just like alloc... whenever you call a method with the word copy in it... by convention you are in charge of releasing whatever object was returned.  That's all I can really make with the size of the picture.